# GAS: How to change all values of a neighbor column? (code not working)

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Apps Script which I want to use to do this: get the text of all cells of column G of my sheet, extract some data from this text (dates embebed in text) and put the result in the column H. I can extract the date from the raw text. But I cann't iterate and put it in the neighbur column ("H"), because, when I try this with this code, nothing happens. And I got this logs:

[image]

This is my code:

```
function changeNextCell() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange();
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  for (var i = 2; i <= numRows; i++) {
      var rawText = range.getCell(i,6).getValue();
      var newDate = findDate(rawText);
      range.getCell(i,6).setValue(newDate);
    }  
}


function findDate (text){
  text1 = text.split("Date:");
date = 'no date informed';
for (var i=0; i<text1.length; i++) {
     text2 = text1[i].split(" ");
     if (text2[1] === 'open:'){
         date = text2[2];
     }
  }
  return date;
}
```

Can someone tell me what to fix to it work as it should do? (replace all values in next column) THANKS in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that you want to get all values on column G, but on the code you do a `getActiveRange`. Well, that function only returns what's selected on your screen. If you haven't selected manually the whole column G before running the it will indeed do nothing. Which is consistent with what you're saying.

Well, it's either that or you're mixing what `Range.getCell` does. I'm not sure where the misconception is. Hopefully the code provided will help you understand.

Lastly, getting and setting the values cell by cell is not a good approach, mainly because it's much slower. You should get it all at once, loop through, then set it all. Here's how I'd do it:

```js
function setColumnHfromG() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var input = s.getRange(2, 7, s.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
  //I'm skipping the first row here as this seemed to be your intention
  //Also, I'm considering the column (G) is fully filled. i.e. I'm not checking for empty cells
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    output.push([ findDate(input[i][0]) ]);

  s.getRange(2, 8, output.length, 1).setValues(output);
}
```

If you want to "detect" which column is the selected range, but not force the user to select the whole column. You could do:

```js
function setNextColumn() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var column = s.getActiveRange().getColumn();
  var input = s.getRange(2, column, s.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    output.push([ findDate(input[i][0]) ]);

  s.getRange(2, column+1, output.length, 1).setValues(output);
}
```

ps: I believe you `findDate` function is correct, but if it isn't at least it'll be easier to fix it after you got the script to do something.

Comment: It's just... a perfect answer. You should consider write a book on GAS. I'm talking seriously. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! BTW there's already [an Apps Script book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023210.do?cmp=af-prog-book-product_cj_9781449318529_7167871), written by a [fellow Top Contributor](http://stackoverflow.com/users/964103/james-ferreira).

Comment: I just bought this book! (on Kindle). But I need it on paper (to make notes with pencil). So, I'll buy another copy!

Comment: James is writing a 2nd edition, with many more updates, I suggest you wait a little while then :)

Comment: Great news. I thought it was a little outdated (forms, eg). I'll buy the 2sd edition.

Comment: Hi, @Henrique Abreu, could "give me a hand" with this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19701548/google-apps-script-how-to-fix-truncating-output-error-when-processing-text-fr/19701951?noredirect=1#comment29266112_19701951